# Vaadin 14 GridPro element does not reflect change in UI

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid, vaadin14

I'm using a GridPro component for a CustomField. The grid is backed by a ListDataProvider. The grid is initialized like so:

```
this.grid.addEditColumn(new ValueProvider<Item, String>() {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public String apply(final Item source) {
        return (String)source.get(prop.getName());
    }
}, new TextRenderer<Item>(new ItemLabelGenerator<Item>() {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public String apply(final Item item) {
        String val = (String)item.get(prop.getName());
        return StringTools.isValidString(val) ? val : "";
    }

})).text(new ItemUpdater<Item, String>() {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void accept(final Item item, final String newValue) {
        Item dataProviderItem = (Item)dataProvider.getId(item);
    dataProviderItem.set(prop.getName(), newValue);
TableField.this.dataProvider.refreshItem(dataProviderItem);
    }
}).setHeader(prop.getName());
```

The problem I'm having is that when I'm editing a cell its content is not updated in the UI and it still shows the old value. The renderer properly returns the new value, and the ValueProvider as well sets the new text value correctly.

Comment: Do you mean that when the client submits changes to the field (enter or click outside), the value on clientside reverts back to its old value?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The clientside value (i.e. what the cell in the UI displays) reverts to what it previously was, even though the renderer correctly returns the new value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was the the POJO I was using as a type parameter to GridPro did not have an invariable ID thus the dataProvider.refreshItem was not able to find it in the backing set and update it. See https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/18453090/grid-with-editor-can-t-save-changed-data for details.

Answer (score 1):

You are at least setting it up in overly complicated manner. Java 8 allows you to setup text field in `GridPro` with just few lines of code like this. Say you have `Grid<Person>` and `Person#getFirstName` returns the first name and `Person#setFirstName` respectively is the setter for the property, you need only this. Calling `DataProvider#refreshItem` is not needed, as `GridPro` will do this internally as well.

```
grid.addEditColumn(Person::getFirstName)
        .text((item, newValue) -> item.setFirstName(newValue))
        .setHeader("First name");
```

See more examples in [documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/ds/components/grid-pro).

Comment: Unfortunately I need that overly complicated solution as I'm backing my entire dataset on Items which have an undetermined structure. 
Nevertheless, the solution was provided by you here: https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/18453090/grid-with-editor-can-t-save-changed-data and it was that the Item did not had an invariable ID so that the dataProvider.refreshItem would be able to find it and refresh it. I created a simple POJO that had an invariable ID and used that as type param for the GridPro and it works ok.
Thank you